# Insert x00 into char field using insert statements

Tags: database, db2

How to insert ascii value x00 to char fields  in a table using insert query.

Comment: err, what platform?  And how is the table defined?  Why are you attempting to insert this specific value?

Comment: I need to do it in db2 db. Table has 2 fields id and name and i need to add the charater at the end of each name. Already some rows are there with such values. but these rows were created using java code. Now i need to create it using command window itself.

Comment: What DB2 platform - iSeries, LUW, z, etc.  And why do you need this inserted at the end of each name?  Can we get the actual table definition?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Actually, you can just select hexidecimal constants in your select(insert, etc) statement:

```
SELECT x'00' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Be warned, if you're using a character besides the null terminator (ASCII `\0`), then the result will depend on your database's encoding. For example, running `SELECT x'F5' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` on my Mainframe machine (EBCDIC), I get `5`, while on my LUW machine (which I believe is Unicode), I get `õ`.

Comment: So what does he need to give to `CHR` for it to return ASCII `x'00'`?